# Implemented z score functions that seems not give the correct answers

Tags: python, statistics

I have looking for some implementation of a z score function and found out this paper:
[article](https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/26/12/2971/2385980#38382029)

According to the paper the variance is like that:

```
def get_variance(kmer_list, kmer_counts, kmer_exected):
    variance = defaultdict(float)
    for kmer in kmer_list:
        suffix = float(kmer_counts[kmer[1:]])
        prefix = float(kmer_counts[kmer[:-1]])
        middle = float(kmer_counts[kmer[1:-1]])
        # to catch the divide by zero error
        if middle == 0:
            variance[kmer] = 0.0
        else:
            variance[kmer] = kmer_exected[kmer] * ((middle - prefix) / (middle - suffix) / math.pow(middle, 2))
    return variance
```

And the z score is like:

```
def get_z_scores(kmer_list, kmer_counts, expec_kmers, var_kmers):
    z_scores = defaultdict(float)
    for kmer in kmer_list:
        if var_kmers[kmer] == 0:
            z_scores[kmer] = 0.0
        else:
            z_scores[kmer] = kmer_counts[kmer] - expec_kmers[kmer] / math.sqrt(var_kmers[kmer])
    return z_scores
```

The my count implementation is like that:

```
def get_kmer_counts(sequence, alphabet, min_k, max_k):
    """ 
    Counts number of k-mers (kmin <= k <= kmax) in a sequence.
    Inputs:
    sequence = sequence string defined by an alphabet.
    min_k - minimum kmer length (int)
    max_k - maximum kmer length (int)
    Output:
    A dictionary with keys of k-mers and values as counts (int) and
    the length of the sequence data collected as a tuple.
    To the script work this function must have count kmers from
    mink-2 to max_k.
    """    
    seq, alphabet = sequence.upper(), alphabet.upper()
    counts = Counter()
    seq_len = len(seq)
    for k in range(min_k, max_k + 1):
        for i in range(0, seq_len - (k + 1)):
            kmer = seq[i:i + k]
            if all(base in set(alphabet) for base in kmer):
                counts[kmer] += 1
    return counts
```

The expected counts is like this:

```
def get_expected_kmers_markov_higher(kmer_list, kmer_counts):
    """Calculates the expected value of all palindrome kmers in a sequence.
    Inputs:
    pal_lst = list of palindromes (str)
    counts = dictionary of kmer counts
    Output:
    expected - dictionary with expected values for all palindromes.
    The expected values are calculated as:
       E(C(W)) = C(W1-Wn-1) * C(W2-Wn) / C(W2-Wn-1)
    """
    expected = defaultdict(float)
    for kmer in kmer_list:
        suffix = float(kmer_counts[kmer[1:]])
        prefix = float(kmer_counts[kmer[:-1]])
        middle = float(kmer_counts[kmer[1:-1]])
        # to catch the divide by zero error
        if middle == 0:
            expected[kmer] = 0.0
        else:
            expected[kmer] = (prefix * suffix) / middle
    return expected
```

However my z scores for kmer in NZ_CP009610.1 Haemophilus influenzae strain Hi375 chromosome are very bizarre:

```
defaultdict(float,
            {'AAATTT': -1347833.5034819366,
             'AACGTT': -171787.35254952748,
             'AAGCTT': -146769.5429434471,
             'AATATT': -559475.4757181505,
             'ACATGT': -19497.440162201317,
             'ACCGGT': -4665.704469880016,
             'ACGCGT': -44220.92008247342,
             'ACTAGT': -20780.691999638915,
             'AGATCT': -84993.60788549489,
             'AGCGCT': -32713.970359670995,
             'AGGCCT': -6946.826069022764,
             'AGTACT': -56359.103790146386,
             'ATATAT': -145308.87432388903,
             'ATCGAT': -80899.87600902142,
             'ATGCAT': -223514.65456613328,
             'ATTAAT': -778442.9091555111,
             'CAATTG': -691815.5554949252,
             'CACGTG': -98012.67310140815,
             'CAGCTG': -115149.41232218238,
             'CATATG': -206560.2329861765,
             'CCATGG': -23560.724213074038,
             'CCCGGG': -3443.6541067615763,
             'CCGCGG': -23083.190137390997,
             'CCTAGG': -16746.59421395531,
             'CGATCG': -78821.19846789229,
             'CGCGCG': -37080.69102559708,
             'CGGCCG': -4990.897566858435,
             'CGTACG': -47795.73920832729,
             'CTATAG': -74185.91084089952,
             'CTCGAG': -40042.09840232448,
             'CTGCAG': -225587.71665440983,
             'CTTAAG': -276075.60476808256,
             'GAATTC': -603573.451219751,
             'GACGTC': -47329.450124072515,
             'GAGCTC': -65887.95816147391,
             'GATATC': -251363.3482040272,
             'GCATGC': -23832.94590888017,
             'GCCGGC': -2958.2003374628193,
             'GCGCGC': -34378.624032136184,
             'GCTAGC': -22562.60559176558,
             'GGATCC': -64378.81159393075,
             'GGCGCC': -37356.36760647725,
             'GGGCCC': -7446.63926595547,
             'GGTACC': -45840.501511340495,
             'GTATAC': -68423.58951422838,
             'GTCGAC': -35211.26669797196,
             'GTGCAC': -198979.63560124647,
             'GTTAAC': -317503.74949876923,
             'TAATTA': -873054.9889592085,
             'TACGTA': -101731.64499659775,
             'TAGCTA': -104525.06189383658,
             'TATATA': -196323.61270456627,
             'TCATGA': -29151.333612451388,
             'TCCGGA': -2979.6671758235466,
             'TCGCGA': -42898.45154478854,
             'TCTAGA': -29087.25274486562,
             'TGATCA': -116740.2664640635,
             'TGCGCA': -71820.85042373739,
             'TGGCCA': -11620.498346958928,
             'TGTACA': -63712.42693965624,
             'TTATAA': -192878.33644108364,
             'TTCGAA': -62447.89966926324,
             'TTGCAA': -376467.1497269339,
             'TTTAAA': -858581.8433225563})
```

There are any point that I am messing up in my implementations?
Seems that they are way off the values that the authors get in the text.
Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: can you reduce the code to the relevant parts.. also with no data no one will be able to reproduce your error

Comment: ```kmer_counts[kmer] - expec_kmers[kmer] / math.sqrt(var_kmers[kmer]``` this is wrong. you need to subtract first before dividing, i.e ```(obs - mean )/sd```

Comment: My friend wolf not stupid because the influenza genome is big I linked the article for who needed to use to download the data. But I will check it out our tip. Thank you very much by your attention and time.